# Rollup make bundle by command line from Gulp but from rollup-stream package not

Tags: typescript, gulp, child-process, rollupjs

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Permutatrix/rollup-stream/issues/31)
When using rollup-stream package im receiving the following error:

```
[10:01:14] Using gulpfile ~/myUser/myProjectFolder/myTestProject/gulpfile.js  
[10:01:14] Starting 'default'...  
[10:01:14] Starting 'transpile-it'...  
[10:01:16] Finished 'transpile-it' after 2.11 s  
[10:01:16] Starting 'bundle-it'...  

[10:01:16] 'bundle-it' errored after 31 ms  

[10:01:16] TypeError: parse is not a function in /home/myUser/myProjectFolder/myTestProject/obj/main.js  
    at error (/home/myUser/myProjectFolder/myTestProject/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:185:14)  
    at Promise.resolve.then.catch.err (/home/myUser/myProjectFolder/myTestProject/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:9182:6)  
    at <anonymous>  
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)  

[10:01:16] 'default' errored after 2.15 s
```

im using in this case the following package.json:

```
{  
  "name": "myTestProject",  
  "version": "1.0.0",  
  "description": "",  
  "main": "index.js",  
  "scripts": {  
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"  
  },  
  "keywords": [],  
  "author": "",  
  "license": "ISC",  
  "devDependencies": {  
    "@types/node": "^9.4.7",  
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",  
    "gulp-typescript": "^4.0.1",  
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^9.1.0",  
    "rollup-plugin-copy": "^0.2.3",  
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.3.0",  
    "rollup-stream": "^1.24.1",  
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",  
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0"  
  },  
  "dependencies": {  
    "asciify": "^1.3.5"  
  }  
}
```

and the following gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');  
var rollup = require('rollup-stream');  
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');  
var commonjs = require('rollup-plugin-commonjs');  
var resolve = require('rollup-plugin-node-resolve');  
var copy = require('rollup-plugin-copy');  
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');  
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');  
gulp.task('transpile-it', function () {  
    return tsProject.src()  
        .pipe(tsProject())  
        .pipe(gulp.dest('obj'));  
});  
gulp.task('bundle-it', function () {  
    return rollup({  
            exports: 'named',  
            sourcemap: false,  
            input: 'obj/main.js',  
            format: 'cjs',  
            plugins: [  
                commonjs(),  
                resolve({  
                    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.flt']  
                }),  
                copy({  
                    "node_modules/asciify/lib/figlet-js/fonts/short.flf": "prd/fonts/short.flf",  
                    verbose: true  
                })  
            ]  
        })  
        .pipe(source('main.js'))  
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./prd'));  
});  
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('transpile-it', 'bundle-it'));
```

To solve this problem I changed to become calling rollup direct with child_process package plus the following rollup.config.js file and all works right:

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';  
import resolve  from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';  
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';      
export default {  
  exports: 'named',   
  sourceMap: true,  
  input: 'obj/main.js',  
  output: {  
    file: './prd/main.js',  
    format: 'cjs'  
  },  
  plugins: [  
    commonjs(),  
    resolve({  
      extensions: [ '.js', '.json', '.flt' ],  
    }),  
    copy({  
       "node_modules/asciify/lib/figlet-js/fonts/short.flf": "prd/fonts/short.flf",  
       verbose: true  
    })  
  ]  
};
```

the gulpfile.js file becomes:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');  
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');  
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');  
var cp = require('child_process');  
gulp.task('transpile-it', function () {  
    return tsProject.src()  
        .pipe(tsProject())  
        .pipe(gulp.dest('obj'));  
});  
gulp.task('bundle-it', function () {  
    const child = cp.exec('rollup -c', [], (error, stdout, stderr) => {  
        if (error) {  
            throw error;  
        }  
        let logIfNotNull = function (value) {  
            if (Boolean(value)) {  
                console.log(value);  
            }  
        }  
        logIfNotNull(error);          
        logIfNotNull(stderr);  
        logIfNotNull(stdout);  
    });  
    return child;  
});  
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('transpile-it', 'bundle-it'));
```

The configuration is the same, i just called by shell and not with rollup-stream package, there is something wrong with rollup-stream package ?

Full script to reproduce:

```
mkdir -p myTestProject/{obj,prd,src/M}
cd myTestProject
npm init -y
npm install -D typescript gulp gulp-typescript @types/node rollup-stream vinyl-source-stream rollup-plugin-commonjs rollup-plugin-node-resolve rollup-plugin-copy
npm install -D gulp@next
npm install -S asciify
cat <<EOT> ./tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
EOT
cat <<EOT> ./gulpfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rollup = require('rollup-stream');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var commonjs = require('rollup-plugin-commonjs');
var resolve = require('rollup-plugin-node-resolve');
var copy = require('rollup-plugin-copy');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');
gulp.task('transpile-it', function () {
    return tsProject.src()
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('obj'));
});
gulp.task('bundle-it', function () {
    return rollup({
            exports: 'named',
            sourcemap: false,
            input: 'obj/main.js',
            format: 'cjs',
            plugins: [
                commonjs(),
                resolve({
                    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.flt']
                }),
                copy({
                    "node_modules/asciify/lib/figlet-js/fonts/short.flf": "prd/fonts/short.flf",
                    verbose: true
                })
            ]
        })
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./prd'));
});
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('transpile-it', 'bundle-it'));
EOT
cat <<EOT> ./src/M/AuxClass.ts
class AuxClass{
    getMessage(){
        return "Class Works!";
    }
}
export { AuxClass }
EOT
cat <<EOT> ./src/main.ts
import { AuxClass } from "./M/AuxClass"
export class main {
  init() {
    let a = new AuxClass();
    let text = a.getMessage();
    let fontName = "short";
    let callback = function(err: any, value: any): void {
      if (err != null) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(value);
    };
    var asciify = require("./../node_modules/asciify/index.js");
    asciify(text, fontName, callback);
  }
}
let m = new main();
m.init();
EOT
```

Comment: And what is the `parse` that `is not a function` in main.js?

Comment: There is no "parse" on all workflow including code to cause this error, the script to reproduce the error added above, "parse" looks to be inside rollup package code, is possible the transpiler is translating someting on typescript to "parse".

Comment: I recomend to try remove plugins and check, how will it work. Also you can try to make minimal reproducing example with finding simpliest code, that produces error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to roll back `rollup-plugin-commonjs` to 8.4.1. That fixed it for me.

Comment: using now: npm install -D typescript gulp gulp-typescript @types/node rollup-stream vinyl-source-stream rollup-plugin-commonjs@8.4.1 rollup-plugin-node-resolve rollup-plugin-copy

Comment: Rolling back to 8.4.1 also worked for me.  Can someone explain why that fixes the problem though?  Thanks.

Comment: 9.0.0 has rollup as a peer dependency and somehow that causes this error.